# Deleting from a .txt file

Tags: python

So I have this problem:
I want to delete a specific item from a .txt file but when I launch the file It just closes!
If I have my code like this It just closes:

```
nc = input('Name:')
f = open("info.txt", "w")
for line in f: 
  if line != nc: 
    f.write(line)
```

But when I change my code like this:

```
nc = input('Name:')
f = open("info.txt", "w")
for line in f: 
  if line != nc: f.write(line)
```

It works until I get to the point of code when I`m deleting something and then just closes and deletes everything in the .txt file!

Someone, please help me!

Comment: open your file for reading, read it, then write it back with the line removed. check duplicate link

Answer (score -1, accepted):

Try changing the open list to "w+". Like this:

```
f = open("info.txt", "w+")
```

Comment: That actually worked. Thank you!

Comment: Ok now it doesn't close the program but It still deletes everything

Comment: Close it properly